# Уникальный js скрипт для mysql записи php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
}
$host = 'localhost';
    $db   = '';
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM comments_task WHERE id_t_c = ".$_GET['id']." order by id_c_t desc");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $id = $row['id_c_t'];
    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <td style='padding-left: 10px;'>
    <a style='font-size: 14px;color: #777777;' id='kurl' href='javascript: goToPage(".$id.");'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a>
    <a href='/?id=".$id."'>ывффыв</a>
    <script type= 'text/javascript'>
function goToPage(tx)
{
    var tx = '".$id."';
    var url = document.getElementById('kurl');
    document.location.href = '/fun/awg.php/?id=".$id."&id_t=".$_GET['id']."';
}
</script>
    </td></tr></table>
```

В этом коде есть скрипт который выводит иконку для каждой записи на определенную функцию php. В этом скрипте get параметрами передается id который равен id записи из таблицы mysql. Суть в том что передается только 1 id для всех записей.
Я вывел переменную tx = id записи из таблицы.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А что сейчас работает не так и какой должен быть результат?

Comment: @ya.ymer Сейчас при нажатии на любую ссылку, которые выводятся с записями mysql id=одном id из 10, на какую бы мы запись не нажали. Цикл с скриптом почему то не происходит.

Comment: так Вы сами указываете конкретный id - `id_t_c = $_GET['id']`, с чего бы он выводил все?

Comment: @ya.ymer это id для связывающих таблиц. Допустим id_t_c = 2, а записей в таблице где  id_t_c = 2 около 100 шт.

Comment: Проблема в том что у вас 20 функций с одинаковым именем. Вопрос - почему?

Comment: @u_mulder увидел в коде, и правда, хорошо, как тогда задать имя для функции на основании $id = $row['id_c_t'];

Comment: Вы понимаете что у вас 20 функций делают __одно и то же__? И вы теперь хотите создать 20 функций с разными именами, но они по прежнему будут делать __одно и то же__. Может вы не понимаете зачем нужны функции?

Comment: @u_mulder как тогда реализовать данную задачу, т.к для каждой записи должна быть своя ссылка с get параметрами?

Comment: функцию `goToPage` выведите за пределы цикла, а в цикле просто ее вызывайте, в чем проблема?

Comment: Передать что-то в функцию, а она уже с этим переданным значением что-то сделает?

Comment: Но в функции выводятся переменные, которые можно получить только с помощью цикла (id записи), верно же?

Comment: Значит функцию надо __вызывать__ в цикле, передавая определённый аргумент, а __определить__ функцию надо один раз.

Comment: @u_mulder как тогда это сделать? Можете помочь с кодом?

Comment: @u_mulder я вот думаю если вызвать функцию только с  ссылкой а get параметры передавать из `<a id='kurl' href='javascript: goToPage(".$id.");'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно так это должно выглядеть

Сначала функцию выводим за пределы цикла, потом в самом цикле "вызываем" ее передавая нужные нам параметры.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM comments_task WHERE id_t_c = " . $_GET['id'] . " order by id_c_t desc");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style='padding-left: 10px;'>
                <a style='font-size: 14px;color: #777777;' id='kurl' href='javascript: goToPage("<?= $row['id_c_t'] ?>", "<?= $_GET['id'] ?>");'>
                    <i class='fa fa-trash-alt'></i>
                </a>
                <a href='/?id=<?= $row['id_c_t'] ?>'>link</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php } ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function goToPage(id, id_t) {
        document.location.href = '/fun/awg.php/?id=' + id + '&id_t=' + id_t;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое, только немного изменить `<a style='font-size: 14px;color: #777777;' id='kurl' href='javascript: goToPage(".$row['id_c_t'].", ".$_GET['id'].");'>`

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин еще хочу сказать что присваивать id ссылке в цикле неправильно, т.к атрибут id должен быть уникальным, имейте ввиду

Comment: Спасибо, это уберем)

Comment: ваша правка не корректна, `while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>` как видите у меня здесь закрывающая конструкция php и дальше идет html. если вы запишите так `href='javascript: goToPage(".$row['id_c_t'].", ".$_GET['id'].");'` то вместо параметров получите текст, просто `.$row['id_c_t'].`  и `.$_GET['id'].`

Comment: Я понял, не увидел закрывающий php

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за код)